# TypeError: $.material is undefined in material design for boostrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I am using a library from [GITHUB FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)

Now I have added all the CSS and JS files still in my console I get the error:

> TypeError: $.material is undefined

I want the input effects as it shows in demo but due to this error its now working.

I have added the files like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/css/bootstrap-material-design.css'); ?>">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/css/ripples.min.css'); ?>">

    <script src="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/js/material.js'); ?>"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/js/ripples.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/js/jquery.nouislider.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    <!--SNACKBAR BOOSTRAP TOAST -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/snackbar/snackbar.min.css'); ?>">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('fms_material_design/snackbar/snackbar.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Comment: @DaRoGa i cant tell how but i solved this but i viewed the page source of that demo page of this library and put the js and css as they were in demo page's source and it solved my problem